# Creating pixel art by tracing full resolution image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector-graphics, image-sprites

I'm trying to teach myself pixel art using Pixen or Photoshop. I'm terrible at free handing it and I'm trying to import a full resolution sprite as a background to trace. Each program downgrades my imported image to 32x32 to match the resolution I'm working at. Obviously this destroys the quality and makes me unable to trace. Is there any way to use an image as a bottom layer that is not really part of the image you're working on?

Comment: At first, create a new blank pixel art with the same res. of your full res. tracing image, now you should be able to trace. Then resize the pixel art to 32x32. Will this help you in anyway? let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a windows user, you can simply open the source image in your favorite image viewer, and using GhostWin[1], make Photoshop transparent so that the source image is visible beneath your canvas.

On Mac, Afloat[2] seems to be able to do something similar, but I've never used it.

[1] http://www.ghostwindows.com/
[2] http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/